# Convergence Intervals

Tags: sequences-and-series

Consider the function $$f(x) = \frac{x}{1-x}$$
We know that for $x\in(0,1)$,
$$f(x) = x\cdot\frac1{1-x} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty x^{k+1} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty x^{k} - 1$$
Now, notice that:
$$\frac{x}{1-x} = \frac{x^{-1}}{x^{-1}}\frac{x}{1-x} = \frac1{x^{-1}-1}$$
Which reveals that for $x\in(1,\infty)$
$$f(x) = -\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^{-k}$$
So we now have two different infinite sum representations for $f$ across $[0,\infty)\cap\{x\neq1\}$.

My question is as follows:
Given a function $f$ which has a taylor series expansion for some interval, are there approaches or theorems which allow you to find other expansions which work on other intervals? There wasn't any magic in what I did above, I just happened to notice I could write the function in a slightly different way. Wondering if there are known approaches or relationships like this for other functions.

Comment: Your analysis is fine.  And this is a standard trick to find, for example, an asymptotic large argument expansion for a function.